# How to make Select Query to suit null conditions and not null condition

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select first_name,last_name from contacts where first_name = 'somevalue' and last_name = 'somevalue'
```

I get these values via ajax

Sample table contacts

```
id | first_name | last_name

1  | Rahul      |  Roy
2  | Rohit      |  NULL
```

Now when via ajax I get first_name as "Rahul" and last_name as "Roy" query returns 1 records (the first one)

But if I get first_name as "Rohit" and last_name is empty I get below query

```
select first_name,last_name from contacts where first_name = 'Rohit' and last_name = ''
```

I get no records.But actually I want to get the record with id 2 from above table.

How can my query fullfill both conditions in just one query

Comment: ' '  it is consider as NULL

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT first_name,last_name 
FROM contacts 
WHERE first_name = 'Rohit' and (last_name IS NULL OR last_name = 'your value')
```

Here you go!

Answer (score 0):

USE NULL for this condition, Can you try this?

```
select first_name,last_name 
from contacts 
where first_name = 'Rohit' and last_name = ''
```

to

```
select first_name,last_name 
from contacts 
where first_name = 'Rohit' 
      and (last_name IS NULL || last_name='somevalue')
```

If you want Last name not to be empty

```
select first_name,last_name 
from contacts 
where first_name = 'Rohit' 
      and last_name IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "is null" instead of "=''".

i.e.

```
select first_name,last_name from contacts where first_name = 'Rohit' and last_name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select first_name,last_name 
from contacts 
where first_name = 'Rahul' and (last_name = 'Roy' or last_name is null);
```